# How do I store data added in react-draft-wysiwyg Editor to my state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using a react-draft-wysiwyg Editor for adding articles. I am not sure how to store the data that is added in the editor to my state.
This is what I am doing:

```
<Editor
  editorState={details}
  toolbarClassName="toolbarClassName"
  wrapperClassName="wrapperClassName"
  editorClassName="editorClassName"
  onEditorStateChange={editorStateChange}
/>

const [details, setDetails] = useState(EditorState.createEmpty());
 const editorStateChange = (details) => {
    setDetails(details);
  };
```

How do I store the content?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to displayed local content react-draft-wysiwyg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55793428/how-to-displayed-local-content-react-draft-wysiwyg)

Comment: No, I need to store the data in my state and send it to an API

Answer (score 0):

Use `.getCurrentContent().getPlainText()` to get the plain text from the editor after each change, and save it in some external state of yours:

```
const [details, setDetails] = useState(EditorState.createEmpty());
const [plainText, setPlainText] = useState('');

const editorStateChange = (details) => {
  setDetails(details);
  setPlainText(details.getCurrentContent().getPlainText());
};
```

Comment: It is working but how does it store the editing info? Like which text is bold and what font etc?